# What defines left and right in graphs and trees?

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory

I'm learning about tree traversals and I can't seem to find any clear rules for how DFS or BFS algorithms decide which path to take first. I've seen variations of `left first` or `least first`.

Is left taken as being first child in the list?
Does this mean that (for a given node) the depth of a vertex in a graph that is part of a cycle is taken using the leftward path?
Also doesn't using a 'least first' rule make for a slower algorithm?
Thanks

Comment: How does that arbitrary nature translate to code? Wouldn't people come out with very different paths?

Comment: "left" and "right" are just arbitrary presentational names. In binary search trees, "left" typically holds elements that sort below and "right" typically holds elements that sort above some node. Nothing prevents you from breaking the convention, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Left is only meaningful for trees where the child nodes are oldered. Otherwise usually the author refers to `first in the list of child nodes`. Depth of a vertex is also not well defined in a graph that is not a tree, but if you refer to depth with respect to a given node that would usually be the shortest distance from the starting node.

I am not sure what does `least first` mean but if it refers to the key values of nodes and there is no ordering in the child nodes, finding the least will take more time of course.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thankyou that makes it clear,
Can I ask why this was downvoted so much? I did give a reason as to why research didn't seem to help me.

Comment: @dnv I think the people that downvoted your question are the best to answer this question. I found it reasonable and that is why I gave you an answer.

Comment: I figured, and I'm very grateful :)